# Print Bacode on Odoo Pos Receipt

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, xml, odoo-8

I'm doing an Odoo 8 Implementation, and have a requirement from a customer, to print the Pos Receipt reference as a Barcode in the bottom of the receipt.
I managed to print a sample by:

- Downloaded the barcode-jquery plugin, and extracted under point_of_sale/static/src/js/
- Created JS file called barcode.js with the following code

```js
 $("#bcTarget").barcode("1234567890123", "ean13");
```

- Added the following lines in pos.xml, under PosTicket template

```js
<div id="bcTarget"></div><br /> 

<xpath expr="." position="inside">
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="/point_of_sale/static/src/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>   
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="/point_of_sale/static/src/js/jquery-barcode.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="/point_of_sale/static/src/js/barcode.js" />
</xpath>
```

But my problem I didn't manage to print orde.pos_reference as a Barcode itself, any idea please?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your case with barcode is that you need to extend the client side qweb template and widgets for the POS to be able to add that behavior. In Odoo JS Framework it's not a matter of have the code that works, It's more about where to put the code that works and how extends properly Odoo widgets
You could start with this js in a module(for the example **pos_barcode_module**):

```js
openerp.pos_barcode_module = function (instance) {

    var _t = instance.web._t;
    var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;
    var session = instance.session;

    var ReceiptScreenWidget = instance.point_of_sale.ReceiptScreenWidget;

    ReceiptScreenWidget.include({
        refresh: function() {
            var order = this.pos.get('selectedOrder');
            //get the needed reference or references for the products or the order itself
            this._super();
            //apply js transformations to:
            //$('.pos-receipt-container', this.$el)
        }
    });
};
```

Also maybe you need to extend the client side qweb template PosTicket to add the html node container(s) for the barcode(s)
And this is just one of the used POS Tickets, could happen that need to deal with the Print Proxy for the Odoo POS and it will not be the same widgets/templates
Or you need it for boths...
It's not as easy as it seems
My two cents

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this much of code in your xml template:

```
 <t t-if='receipt.barcode'>
                <barcode encoding="EAN13"><t t-esc="receipt.barcode"/></barcode>
                <br/>
            </t>
```

And barcode is there in receipt..